# "Run `npm audit` for more detail " warning

Tags: npm-install

In npm version 6.0.0, executing the `npm install` command reports this message:

```
up to date in 13.576s
[!] 52 vulnerabilities found [15904 packages audited]
Severity: 8 low | 40 moderate | 4 high
Run `npm audit` for more detail
```

Why does this appear, and how can it be disabled?

Comment: Try running `npm audit`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It’s a new feature, introduced with npm@6. It shows all vulnerabilities your dependencies got (excluding peerDependencies)

You can disable the warning for single package installations with the `--no-audit` flag.

To deactivate it for all installations you can execute `npm set audit false`